# How to find elements of one vector that aren't in another (not using setdiff)

Tags: r, set-difference

I have two vectors,

```r
x <- c(1,2,2,3,4)

y <- c(1,2,3)
```

And I want to get another vector of the elements that are in x that aren't in y; so in this case (2,4).

I've tried using the setdiff() function but this doesn't take into account duplicates (it would return only 4), so I'm not sure how to go about this.

Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible for `y` to have duplicates? E.g., if `x = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4)` and `y = c(1, 2, 2, 3)`, do you want the result `3 4`?

Comment: I mean, it's a question. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe try this:

```
x[-match(y,x,nomatch = 0)]
```

The `nomatch = 0` is necessary to avoid mixing NAs with negative subscripts.

To deal with additional duplicates, as mentioned in the comments, another option might be to use `vsetdiff` from the package **vecsets**:

```
library(vecsets)
x = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4)
y = c(1, 2, 2, 3)
> vsetdiff(x,y)
[1] 3 4
```

Comment: Not sure how complicated OP's dupe cases are, but if `y` has duplicates this will only drop the first one, even  if it is also duplicated in `x`. E.g., `x = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4)` and `y = c(1, 2, 2, 3)` gives `2 3 4`, but my best guess is OP would want `3 4`.

Comment: Neither did OP's example ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for sharing the package!

Answer (score 0):

It won't give the results as discussed by @Gregor, however, it should give the correct results based on the example:

```
x[duplicated(x) | !x %in% y]

[1] 2 4
```

In individual steps:

```
duplicated(x)

[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

!x %in% y

[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

duplicated(x) | !x %in% y

[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering OP's original example and reading @Gregor's comment, I wrote the following function that does what OP wants and also takes into account what @Gregor pointed out

```r
## function to find values in x that are absent in y
x.not.in.y <- function(x, y) {
  # get freq tables for x and y
  x.tab <- table(x)
  y.tab <- table(y)
  # if a value is missing in y then set its freq to zero
  y.tab[setdiff(names(x.tab), names(y.tab))] = 0
  y.tab <- y.tab[names(y.tab) %in% names(x.tab)]
  # get the difference of x and y freq and keep if > 0
  diff.tab <- x.tab[order(names(x.tab))] - y.tab[order(names(y.tab))]
  diff.tab <- diff.tab[diff.tab > 0]
  # output vector of x values missing in y
  unlist(
    lapply(names(diff.tab), function(val) {
      rep(as.numeric(val), diff.tab[val])
    }), 
    use.names = F)
}

# OP's original data
x.not.in.y(x = c(1,2,2,3,4), y = c(1,2,3))
#> [1] 2 4

# @Gregor's data
x.not.in.y(x = c(1,2,2,3,3,4), y = c(1,2,2,3))
#> [1] 3 4

# some other data with extra value in y but absent in y
x.not.in.y(x = c(1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5), y = c(1,2,3,6))
#> [1] 2 2 2 3 3 4 5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>